# How to retrieve an xsl-fo marker out of its page-sequence?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using XSL-FO markers to generate running heads, and I'm having trouble retrieving the book title. I have a workaround, but I thought there must be a more elegant solution. Since the book title only appears as text at the beginning of the book, my marker is not in the same page-sequence as my static-content. Is there a mechanism for retrieving an out-of-page-sequence marker?

I am using XSLT Formatter V 4.3 for my PDF generation, but I'm not married to it.

A very simplified XML example:

```
<book>
<bktitle>Alice in Wonderland</bktitle>
<chapter>
<chaptitle>Chapter 1</chaptitle>
<para>This is the story of Alice in Wonderland.</para>
</chapter>
</book>
```

Snippets of the XSL-FO:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="fm">
  <fo:title>Alice in Wonderland</fo:title>
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
     <fo:block font-variant="small-caps">
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="book">Alice in Wonderland</fo:marker>Alice in Wonderland</fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="body">
  <fo:title>Chapter 1</fo:title>
  <fo:static-content flow-name="header">
     <fo:block><fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="book"/></fo:block>
  </fo:static-content>
  <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
     <fo:block font-variant="small-caps">
        <fo:marker marker-class-name="chapter">Chapter 1</fo:marker>Chapter 1</fo:block>
     <fo:block>This is the story of Alice in Wonderland.</fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you use [`retrieve-boundary="document"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#retrieve-boundary):

```
<fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-boundary="document" retrieve-class-name="book"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I swear I reviewed the spec but I somehow missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your static content really is static -- after all, the book title doesn't change halfway through the book -- use the same logic that put the contents of `bktitle` into the first `fo:page-sequence` to also put it in the `fo:static-content/fo:block`.

The FO formatter would also have one less marker to store and quite a few less marker lookups to perform, though you probably wouldn't see that make a measurable difference to processing speed.